# Delete in data table with ajax C#

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatable, server-side

I want to delete data from the data table I developed with server side. Below are my javascript and controller codes. I know the controller is not very convenient. I'm new to Ajax. Thanks .

```
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#veritablosu").DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Home/GetList",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "datatype": "json"
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "PersonelId", "name": "PersonelId" },
                    { "data": "PersonelAd", "name": "PersonelAd" },
                    { "data": "PersonelSoyad", "name": "PersonelSoyad" },
                    { "data": "PersonelEmail", "name": "PersonelEmail" },
                    { "data": "PersonelCep", "name": "PersonelCep" },

                    {
                        "data": "release_date", "orderable": true, "render": function (data, type, row) {
                            return '<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#myModal">Update</button>'
                        }
                    },

                    {
                        "data": null,
                        render: function (data, type, row) {
                            return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-btn">Delete</button>';
                        }
                    }
                ],


                "serverSide": "true",
                "order": [0, "asc"],
                "language": {
                    "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Turkish.json"
                }

            });
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.delete-btn', function (event) {
            const id = event.currentTarget).data('id');
        });

    public ActionResult PersonelSil(int id)
    {            
        DBModel db = new DBModel();
        var prs = db.Personel.Find(id);
        db.Personel.Remove(prs);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

also i couldn't assign modal(popup) to update button.
I made what I wanted on the https://www.codeply.com/go/YV9eFnJXst site, but unfortunately, when I adapt it to myself, the screen does not appear.
Could it be a version error? my links are as below.

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.1/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/dataTables.semanticui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.9/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

@section scripts{
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/dataTables.semanticui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.1/semantic.min.js"></script>




    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js|https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.9/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.9/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
```

How can I learn this job well, I would be very happy if you could help me in this matter.

Comment: Are you seeing errors in browsers console?

Comment: You need to ask a specific question. Are you getting an error or modal popup not coming up or you are not able to call ajax for delete? Which one?

Comment: Hi, please use id while binding "columns" attribute to datatable. mean your api (/Home/GetList) should return one column with name "id". either you can just rename PersonelId to id or just return identity column of your table from backend/api controller. Actually in case of javascript DataTable, at least one column should there with name id and unique value for this id column. Hope this will help you.